# Multiple buttons, same name but different value?

Tags: flask-wtforms

I would like to put multiple `SubmitFields` into my `Form`, but have them share same `name` and have `value` specified by me that is different than their `label`. Is there a chance I could do that in WTForms?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's impossible in the current version, but there are (probably unsupported) hacks and workarounds:

https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms/issues/205